# An issue with a generic method when passing an array as a parameter

Tags: java

I have the following method that I want to pass arrays of different types:

```
    private < E > void print(E[] arr) {
        for(E s: arr) {
            System.out.println(s + "   ");
        }
    }
```

When I pass a `List<Double>` array to the `print` method, I get the following error:

```
The method print(E[]) in the type IAnalysisMocker is not applicable for the arguments (List<Double>)
```

Is there any suggestions of how to solve it?

Comment: On a sidenote: generics and arrays do not mix well since arrays are covariant, while generics are invariant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass a list (or any iterable), then change the method signature to this:

```
private <E> void print(Iterable<E> iterable) {
    for(E s: iterable) {
        System.out.println(s + "   ");
    }
}
```

As the error says `The method print(E[]) .. is not applicable for the arguments (List<Double>)`, you can't pass a `List<E>` when an array (`E[]`) is expected.

Answer (score 2):

A list of doubles is not the same as an array of doubles. Change the parameters to `List<E> arr` or actually pass it an array.

```
private <E> void print(List<E> list) {
```

If you want it to be the "most generic" then `Iterable<E>` should be the type of the parameter, since the Java for-each loop works for any implementer of this interface:

```
private <E> void print(Iterable<E> list) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most flexible solution would be to use `Iterable<E>` and `Arrays.asList`.

```
private <E> void print(Iterable<E> list) {
    for(E s: list) {
        System.out.println(s + "   ");
    }
}

private <E> void print(E[] list) {
    print(Arrays.asList(list));
}
```

You can then `print` almost anything and either one or the other method will be invoked.